# Build PHP array from query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm currently manually building an array.

```
$this->array_list = array('Alaska' => 'Alaska',
                          'Amanda' => 'Amanda',
                          'America' => 'America',
                          'Anthea' => 'Anthea',
                          'Arena' => 'Arena',
                          'Atlantis' => 'Atlantis'
                         );
```

I have a database that i can query this list from, My question is how do I create the array with key and value once getting the list from the query? Key and Value will always be the same. Using mysql and codeigniter.

Query DB for list, create two arrays and use combine? Has to be an easier way?

Comment: I should of worded the question better "Key and Value will always have the same name as each-other" So if  the key name is foo the value will be foo.

Comment: Something like: `while ( .. read row from db ...) $array[$entry]=$entry;`

Comment: Seems like an xy-question. Can you explain what is it that you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I was using an array to populate dropdown menus via callback for 3rd party program called grocery crud, I needed to use a db instead of the array to populate the dropdown.

Comment: Guess I should of posted on Grocery Crud forum, but I always come here!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. Probably not the best way, feel free to give better way to do this.

```
$sofa_list2 = $this->get_media_model->get_sofas();
            foreach ( $sofa_list2 as $k=>$v )
                {
                  $newkey = $sofa_list2[$k]['collection_name'];
                  $sofa_list2[$k] ["$newkey"] = $sofa_list2[$k] ['collection_name'];
                  unset($sofa_list2[$k]['collection_name']);
                }
 $sofa_list2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $sofa_list2);
```